# Get a Div Value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page containing the following div element:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myDivClass" style="">Some Value</div>
```

How would I retrieve the value ("Some Value") either through JQuery or through standard JS?  I tried:

```
var mb = document.getElementById("myDiv");
```

But the debugger console shows "mb is null".  Just wondering how to retrieve this value.

---- UPDATE ----
When I try the suggestion I get:  $ is not a function

This is part of a JQuery event handler where I am trying to read the value when I click a button.  The handler function is working but it can't interpret the jQuery value it seems:

```
jQuery('#gregsButton').click(function() { 
   var mb = $('#myDiv').text();
   alert("Value of div is: " + mb.value); 
});
```

Comment: Re: "$ is not a function" - Are you sure you've included the jQuery .js file?

Comment: @Chris: i like the way you used `Re:` ;)

Comment: Where are you setting that event handler? Make sure it's in `$(document).ready()` or after `myDiv` in the body of the page (usually a good idea to put scripts at the end).

Comment: you shouldn't use mb.value, just use the variable mb, its a string, i.e alert("value is:" + mb);

Comment: Re: "$ is not a function" - don't use $, use jQuery - the $ is an alias to jQuery and by the looks of your code you aren't using the alias for jQuery - possibly because you are also using prototype etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
myDivObj = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if ( myDivObj ) {
   alert ( myDivObj.innerHTML ); 
}else{
   alert ( "Alien Found" );
}
```

Above code will show the innerHTML, i.e if  you have used html tags inside  div then it will show even those too. probably this is not what you expected. So another solution is to use: innerText / textContent property [ thanx to bobince, see his comment ]

```
function showDivText(){
            divObj = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            if ( divObj ){
                if ( divObj.textContent ){ // FF
                    alert ( divObj.textContent );
                }else{  // IE           
                    alert ( divObj.innerText );  //alert ( divObj.innerHTML );
                } 
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Keep getting the message "myDivObj" is NULL in the debugger.  I'm wondering if the fact that this div's value is dynamic and populated by javaScript is the cause of the problem.  It is a counter is is constantly incrementing.

Comment: There's no such property as `text`, there's `textContent` (DOM Level 3 Core standard) and `innerText` (IE-only). `text()` is the jQuery method that calls either of those.

Answer (score 74):

```
$('#myDiv').text()
```

Although you'd be better off doing something like:

```js
var txt = $('#myDiv p').text();
alert(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"><p>Some Text</p></div>
```

Make sure you're linking to your jQuery file too :)

Comment: +1 - and what if `myDiv` contains other elements that also contain text nodes? How would the OP get only the text of `myDiv` then?

Answer (score 15):

if you div looks like this:

```
<div id="someId">Some Value</div>
```

you could retrieve it with jquery like this:

```
$('#someId').text()
```

Answer (score 6):

your div looks like this:

```
<div id="someId">Some Value</div>
```

With jquery:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         var text = $('#someId').html(); 
         //or
         var text = $('#someId').text();
       };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
jQuery('#gregsButton').click(function() { 
    var mb = jQuery('#myDiv').text(); 
    alert("Value of div is: " + mb); 
});
```

Looks like there may be a conflict with using the $. Remember that the variable 'mb' will not be accessible outside of the event handler. Also, the text() function returns a string, no need to get mb.value.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still very new to this...the problem with the proposed solution above is that the debugger now gives me an error for the line:  var mb  = jQuery('#myDiv').text()
Saying "JQuery" is not recognized...its like the JQuery library is not accessible from inside the function.

Comment: Should have said the message in the debugger is "JQuery is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You could also use innerhtml to get the value within the tag....

Answer (score 0):

You can do get id value by using

```js
test_alert = $('#myDiv').val();
alert(test_alert);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"><p>Some Text</p></div>
```

Comment: I just wanted show another way which is .val(). Everybody just showed text() and html() methods. But when I tried, val() method was also worked for me so I just wanted to share. Why did you downvoted ? Is it a bad thing to share some other ways?

Comment: Not in general, but if the answer is not right - val should be used for input elements, see why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294992/change-value-of-div-using-jquery-val-not-working

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer :)