# How can I submit div data to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I was wondering how can I submit div data to MySQL. Im not used to javascript so I dont really know whats happening on the javascript part but how can I get or input the action="" part and method="" part and can I or should I add value="" to the hidden input???

Form html code:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('hidden_data').value=document.getElementById('showing_data').innerHTML;">
        <input id="hidden_data" name="data" type="hidden"/>
        <div id="showing_data" class="commenttext" contenteditable="true"></div>
        <input type="submit" Value="Enter" id="submitthis">
</form>
```

Comment: Its same. Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827659/get-a-div-value-in-jquery

Comment: That Jquery Im Trying To Do it With this Single Html/javascript Code That I Have above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the hidden field inside the form tag and use the JavaScript to put the value inside it. You can get the hidden field in the `$_POST['hydName']`.
Put the data on the click of the submit button into the hidden field. Keep your action and method of the form same as required. After the click event is fired, it will submit the form to its action URL

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElememtById('hidden').value = document.getElementById('div').innerHtml;" />
```

Comment: @ThinkkSo I have made the changes in my answer

Comment: something like that right??`<form action="url" method="POST" onsubmit="document.getElementById('hidden_data').value=document.getElementById('showing_data').innerHTML;">`