# Change value of div using jquery .val() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div:

```
<div id="libraryDisplay">asdf</div>
```

and this code:

```
$('#libraryDisplay').val(booksList);
```

and booksList is a string. It's still displaying "asdf". Any suggestions?

Comment: div elements don't have a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for form elements. If you're trying to set the text of the `<div>`, use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead:

```
$('#libraryDisplay').text(booksList);
```

If `booksList` is actually an HTML fragment (and you're reasonably sure it's coming from a safe source and doesn't have the potential to corrupt your page) use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('#libraryDisplay').html(booksList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

> $('#libraryDisplay').html(booksList);