# How to pass div value to page using ajax jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one div where timer is set. On submit of page I want div value to insert into database

I am trying to post it using ajax.Here is my code
In this , instead of name I want to send div value.

I tried to get value using getElementById but not getting how to pass it.
or else there any other way to get div value and store it in database.

here is my code:

```
<div id="timecounter" >00:05:00</div>

<script>    
    $("button").click(function() {

    $.post("test_post.php", {
            name: "Donald Duck"
        },
        function(data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: `name: $('#timecounter').text()`

Comment: @PoojaTarlekar, unless I'm missing something, "on submit of page" and "trying to post it using ajax" are contradictory statements. From the code I assume we can ignore "on submit of page".

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHtml property as :-

```
divObj= document.getElementById("timecounter")

   alert (divObj.innerHTML);
```

Refer [link click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827659/get-a-div-value-in-jquery) for all possible scenarios ...

Answer (score 0):

First, find the element. The fastest way is by `ID`. Next, use `innerHTML` to get the HTML content of the element.

```
document.getElementById('timecounter').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `jQuery` in both your question tag and title, here's a jQuery-specific solution to your problem:

```
var timecounter_val = $('#timecounter').html(); // Store HTML of `timecounter` `div` in `timecounter_val` variable.
```

If you want, you can also use javascript to access HTML of the `div` element. Here's how you can do that.

```
var timecounter_val = document.getElementById('timecounter').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.ajax to do the action. [Details on $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
 or you can use the [Details on $.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) which you are currently using, just change the code as below

```
$.post("test_post.php", {
        param: $("timecounter").html()
    },
    function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

In server you can access it using the word **param**

Hope this helps :)