# Extract value regarding "block" inside h1

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to get the value inside the "block" to be able to return it on my google tag manager.

How would you do with a custom JS ?

`<h1 data-fading-in="false" data-fading-out="false" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">Turtle</h1>`

Best

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly do you want to get ? The css property "display" or the content "Turtle" ?

Comment: the content "Turtle"

Comment: _"the content "Turtle" "_ `$("h1").text()` ?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a Div Value in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827659/get-a-div-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try either of these options, both will give you expected results 
`$('h1').text()` or `$('h1').html()`