# How can I get a value from using javascript html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

I want to get a value from a HTML tag using javaScript,
I'm trying to do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="year"> 2021 </span>
</body>
<script>
    const YEAR = document.getElementById('year');
    alert(YEAR);
</script>
</html>
```

Instead of getting 2021 in alert I get **[object HTMLSpanElement]**
So how can get 2021 in YEAR variable ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a Div Value in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827659/get-a-div-value-in-jquery) you need to use `innerHTML`,`textContent` or `innerText`, you just fetched whole element, you need to extract content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `document` object you have access to hundreds of properties methods.
You can use `innerHTML()` to retrieve the html `value` with the selected `id` attribute.

`let year = document.getElementById('year').innerHTML;`

Comment: Or `textContent` or `innerText` and he used `document.getElementById` so he got only elements object. So this is not really good explanation.

Comment: Thank you, now I get what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `innerText`, `innerHTML` or `textContent`, if I change your code a little bit,

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span id="year"> <b>2021</b> </span>
    </body>
    <script>
        const YEAR1 = document.getElementById('year').innerHTML;
        const YEAR2 = document.getElementById('year').innerText;
        const YEAR3 = document.getElementById('year').textContent;
        alert("This is innerHTML :" + YEAR1 + "\n" + "This is innerText :" + YEAR2 + "\n" + "This is textContent :" + YEAR3 + "\n");
    </script>
    </html>
```

You can see that `innerText` or `textContent` is the best way to do it, because `innerHTML` returns string inside your `<span>` and the HTML (or XML) markup contained within the string, including any spacing, line breaks, etc.

`innerText` is very similar to `textContent`, however, there are important differences between them! Put simply, `innerText` is aware of the rendered appearance of text, while `textContent` is not.

Comment: While code only answers may solve the problem they are not welcomed on SO, you should explain the changes so OP actuality learns something for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const YEAR = document.getElementById('year').innerText;
```

> The innerText property of the HTMLElement interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants. As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied it to the clipboard.

For more details check the MDN docs:
[HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Comment: While code only answers may solve the problem they are not welcomed on SO, you should explain the changes so OP actuality learns something for it.

Comment: @ikiK I hope it is better now.